# Redirecting traffic from the browser to localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, proxy

I am developing an application that edits http requests from the browser by adding a transit node. How can this be achieved?

For now I just want to intercept packets from the browser and use foxyproxy to redirect to localhost:7070.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 7070;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Received request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    console.log('Request headers:', req.headers);
    console.log('Request body:', req.body);
    next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

It doesn't output anything. But when I check with curl, it catches.
What could be the problem? foxyproxy settings:
Proxy type: http
ip address: 127.0.0.1
port: 7070

Comment: Does this project helps you? https://github.com/jvilk/mitmproxy-node